# Memory allocation error (I think?) in a dynamically sized shopping list.

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

I've included the code below if anyone would be kind enough to complile it to really see the problem. I'm trying to make a dynamically allocated shopping list to get my used to pointers and memory allocation.

The entries is stored in a 1D char array (seperated by null pointers). Arrays containing the location of the first character and entry length have also been created in order to navigate the list.

The code works for small entries, but when I use a list of large entries (e.g. 'adsjasdkasjdaksdj') suddenly my code thinks the length (strlen(message)) is something like '110040'. To me this looks like a memory error but I'm no computer scientist (more of an amateur coder). I tried extending the memory allocated using realloc() but the problem persists.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've put the code in a loop to take 10 entries for testing purposes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int listEntries = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    //Initial definition and allocation of memory.
    char *list;
    list = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); //allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it.

    int *entryLength; //Array to hold length of each entry.
    entryLength = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); //allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it.

    int *entryStart; //Array to hold start point of each entry.
    entryStart = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)); //allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it.

    char *message; //Array to hold the user input.
    message = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)); //allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it.

    int arraySize = 0; //Variable to hold the size of the array.

    char input[32]; //Char array to take user input (copied to 'message' later)

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        //Obtain user entry.
        printf("Insert entry: \n");
        scanf("%s",input);

    //Transfer string pointer contents to usable char array of known size.
        message = (char *)realloc(message, strlen(input)*sizeof(char));

        int i=0;
        while(input[i] != '\0'){
            message[i] = input[i];
            i++;
        }
        message[i]='\0';

        //Add entry to list.
        listEntries++;

        //Find the current size of list.
        arraySize=0;
        for(i=0;i<listEntries;i++) {
            arraySize+=entryLength[i];
            printf("entryLength[%d] = %d\n",i,entryLength[i]);
        }

        //Reallocate memory to accomodate new data.
        list = (char *)realloc(list, (arraySize+1)*sizeof(char)+2);
        entryLength = (int *)realloc(entryLength,(listEntries*4)*sizeof(int)+2); //Over allocating
        entryStart = (int *)realloc(entryStart,(listEntries*4)*sizeof(int)+2); //For safety in dev.

        //Add new entry to data.
        entryLength[listEntries-1]=(int)strlen(message);
        printf("entryLength[%d] is: %d",listEntries-1,entryLength[listEntries-1]);

        entryStart[listEntries-1]=arraySize;
        //printf("Start point is: %d",entryStart[listEntries-1]);

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++){
            list[i+arraySize] = message[i];
        }

        //Print the new entry
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){
            printf("%c",list[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc` (or `realloc`) in C; it's a `void*`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: `message = (char *)realloc(message, strlen(input)*sizeof(char));` is not large enough to `strcpy(message, input)`, so `message[i]='\0';` in your hand-crafted `strcpy()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Debuggers are not just for "computer scientists". Use it. Also something like valgrind would be helpful to check for memory problems. Both should be the first things to use before asking a question to provide more information.

Comment: Storing the list as one long string with offsets is also a bit unwieldy. Using a `char**` would accomplish about the same thing and might be easier to work with. It also lends itself better to extension (you can switch to storing a struct straightfowardly).

Comment: And `sizeof(char)` is **defined** to yield `1`. It is useless, remove it along with the casts from `void *` to pointers.

Comment: @Olaf I like to multiply it anyway for consistency. I don't usually use `sizeof(char)`, but rather something like this `char* foo = malloc(20 * sizeof*foo);`, but it's the same principle. It doesn't do any harm. It'll be optimized by the compiler anyway.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Using the sizeof the pointer's type (resp. the object it points to) is straight forward and protects against changed declarations of the type. But here OP uses the type, thus adds dangerous redundancy anyway. I'd be fine with e.g. `sizeof(*message)` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses all, @Ryan I wanted to use a 1D array because I assumed it would cost less memory, im planning on exporting this code to an ESP8266 chip that has a very small memory so I can make a text-based shopping list

Comment: `x = realloc(x, some_size)` is always wrong. `realloc` does not free `x` in case of a failure, but overwrites it with `NULL`, causing a memory leak.

Comment: @DanielJour thats interesting, didnt know that. What would you do instead?   I'm currently learning off others and that was how they redefined their memory allocations.

Comment: The error was that I was reallocating memory with the arraySize variable, but not updating the variable to accomodate the new data until after the realloc had taken place.